# Adding stylish conversation in android message conversation

Tags: android, android-layout, inbox

I am trying to develop an application that allows users to chat with each other via SMS.

I have done this job.  But the main problem is that now I am giving much importance to the design of my layout.  I want to make my inbox conversation just like the Android built-in message inbox conversation type.  I am in a fix how to do it. I have googled it, but can't find something helpful.  Anyone can help me with source code would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a thought...create your own very specific and personal-styled listview with your own listview adapter!

Comment: no i have done that. i have a simple list view but i want to make it more attractive and want to have almost the same look as android defualt message does like thread base inbox.

Comment: Thats what i am saying! Override every style and create your own!! The layout of each row can be a bubble for example and you will hide dividers and the stuff!

Comment: yes i really want this what are you saying , but alas can't do that. if you have any sample code it will be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Blog](http://adilsoomro.blogspot.fr/2012/12/android-listview-with-speech-bubble.html) discuss how to make a ListView with speech bubble same as native android message app or some other apps out there. I thing you can find some helpful resources there also source code is available.

Comment: is it possible to have the message inbox separted. I mean to say that ,how to add the conversation for different people . first in the inbox ,it will show the number of sender and after clicking that it will show the conversation between  her and mine.

Comment: you should try adding the number in the listview and when clicking one go the conversation with the person. it will do your job.

Comment: can anyone help me with source code ? please i really do need that.

Comment: i have done that with knowing the class name.i take the class name in a string and then onlistitemclick get the positon and start the activity.But how can i do that in message inbox . Here i don't knw class name .i got stuck help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can create it with a dynamic layout.
first you create a container that will be placed in a scrollview
after that you have to load the data (how many is the message,content of the message).
After you get the data you have to create a child view to be added in the container, you can design the child as you like and add it to the container.

overall it'll be looks like this

scrollview->container->(foreach child) add child;

and the pseudocode

```
Scrollview svList = (ScrollView) findviewbyid(R.id.svList);
LinearLayout llContainer = (LinearLayout) findviewbyid(R.id.llContainer);
new AsyncGetMessage().execute //use asynctask to get message
for(int i=0;i<numberofchild;i++)
{
    llContainer.addView(new Child(message,who)) 
    //who is a bool value to determine your message or your friend message
}
```